# Language injection in IntelliJ IDEA for Grails asset-pipeline plugin

Tags: javascript, grails, intellij-idea, asset-pipeline

I would like to know how does one go about setting up language injection in IntelliJ IDEA for the following block of code.

I want the content within `<asset:script/>` to be treated as JavaScript:

```
<body>
    <asset:script type="text/javascript">
        console.debug("javascript here");
    </asset:script>
</body>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: There is a bug ticket in the JetBrains bug tracker: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-139396
Please vote for it!